# Get payload that caused json parse error in Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, ecmascript-2016

I have the following code for making POST Requests.
I'm not 100% sure about error handling here, but it was important for me that I get body text when request is not successful.

One issue that I still do have is - if server responds with 200 OK but invalid json - can I log that payload?
What would be the correct way of logging for Fetch?

```
           Fetch(data.notificationUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: post_data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then((res) => {

                if (!res.ok) {
                    // Could reject the promise here but than response text wouldn't be available
                    //return Promise.reject(`Response was not OK. Status code: ${res.status} text: ${res.statusText}`);
                    return res.text().then((txt) => `Response was not OK. Status code: ${res.status} text: ${res.statusText}.\nResponse: ${txt}`);
                }
                // response ok so we should return json, could follow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch and determine the payload type by content-type header...
                return res.json();
            }).then((response) => {

                if (response) {
                    // set result
                    // ...

                    // redirect
                    return reply.redirect(data.redirectUrlDirectory);
                }

                return reply(Boom.preconditionFailed(`Did not reply with correct payload! json:'${JSON.stringify(response)}'`));
            }).catch((err) => {

                return reply(Boom.badData(`Could not notify on url ${data.notificationUrl} about the payment ${id}.\nError: "${err}"`));
            });
```

Comment: `res.json()` will return valid json if the body is "parseable" to JSON. If json method fails you should `catch` it, it's a Promise anyway.

Comment: so that was kind of my question - what if body wasn't parseable to JSON? how to read it then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use something like this.

This fist option asumes your service response always the header `"application/json"` and a the pay load simple text which I mock it like this.

```
var app = new express();
app.get('/valid', function(req, res){
  res.json({ok: "ok"});
});
app.get('/invalid', function(req, res){
  res.json("bad json body");
});
```

and the `fetch` json handling should looks like this. The other part of your code looks like good for me.

```
var response2 = res.clone();
return res.json().then((json) => {
    // log your good payload
    try {
      // here we check json is not an object
      return typeof json === 'object' ? json : JSON.parse(json);
    } catch(error) {
       // this drives you the Promise catch
      throw error;
    }    
}).catch(function(error) {
     return response2.text().then((txt) => `Response was not OK. Status code: ${response2.status} text: ${response2.statusText}.\nResponse: ${txt}`);
    //this error will be capture by your last .catch()
});
```

`xxx.clone()` allows you to resolve multiple times the same response and create your own combinations like the previous one.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I tried catch on json() prmise but as you said - I cannot use res.text() at this point. So error usually says something about json not being valid but not the value.

Comment: Well, I realised you can `clone()` the response. let me update my answer.

Comment: awesome thanks!
I wonder how "edge casy" this is. It doesn't feel that what I was asking is unreasonable, but code required to get the invalid payload is not very pretty..
Maybe most people just deal with the error and don't need the body?
In ideal world, I would hope to get it as argument in catch.